# How to get xpath from different urls,returned by start_requests method

Tags: python, xpath, scrapy, web-crawler

Here is my scrapy code:

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider
from scrapy.selector import Selector
import MySQLdb


class AmazonSpider(BaseSpider):
    name = "amazon"
    allowed_domains = ["amazon.com"]
    start_urls = []

    def parse(self, response):
        print self.start_urls

    def start_requests(self):
        conn = MySQLdb.connect(user='root',passwd='root',db='mydb',host='localhost')
        cursor = conn.cursor()
        cursor.execute(
            'SELECT url FROM products;'
            )
        rows = cursor.fetchall()
        for row in rows:
            yield self.make_requests_from_url(row[0])
        conn.close()
```

How can I get the xpath of the urls returned by `start_requests` function?

Note:urls are of different domains, not the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`yield` makes `start_requests` function a generator. Use `for` loop to get every result returned from it.

Like this:

```
...
my_spider = AmazonSpider()
for my_url in my_spider.start_requests():
    print 'we get URL: %s' % str(my_url)
...
```